# WYSIWYG editor/upload functionality strange behaviour (after changing host)

Tags: wysiwyg, hosting, textarea, wyvern

I am running EE 2.1.4 and I needed to make a copy of the website on a new domain (my localhost) for some development. A strange thing happens with the wyvern editor. If I leave (from general configuration) the themes folder and path from the live site, the WYSIWYG editor works ok. If i add my local themes path/folder, the editor gets visibiliy:hidden from a *.js file ckeditor and I can see the editor and the toolbar.

Also the upload functionality for a new entry is not doing anything. No upload popup appears except this error in console "Cannot call method 'dialog' of undefined" in some EE js file.

Did you had this problem before ? I saw that in ckeditor.js line 160 it’s a condition if (!a.editor). That is affecting my editor… Don’t know how to fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need to do is upgrade EE, Wyvern, and CKeditor. Sounds like you're using really old versions, which I don't support.